# Handle "higl-level" errors in a WebView

Tags: cocoa, error-handling, webview

Is there a way to handle different HTML errors in a WebView? Such as: linked CSS file was not found, some JS or DOM error occured.

`webView:didFailLoadWithError:forFrame:` does not handle them (I believe I set the delegate correctly since I receive `webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:` and other messages).

Answer (score 0):

To be notified when a resource such as a css file was not found, set the [WebResourceLoadDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebResourceLoadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003836) of your webview:

```
self.webView.resourceLoadDelegate = self;
```

and implement this delegate method:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView resource:(id)identifier didFailLoadingWithError:(NSError *)error fromDataSource:(WebDataSource *)dataSource {
    NSLog(@"Error loading resource : %@", error);
}
```

That error will include the name and path of the resource the webview failed to load.

In order to see errors thrown by javascript, set the [WebUIDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebUIDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003838):

```
self.webView.UIDelegate = self;
```

and implement this private API delegate method (NOTE: your app should probably not rely on this method because it is from a private API)

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView addMessageToConsole:(NSDictionary *)message {
    NSLog(@"Javascript error : %@",message);
}
```